# CurrentRegion.Row.Count returns incorrect number

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column that contains question numbers and blank cells. For a specific set of questions I need to do calculations that are different from the calculations required for the rest of the workbook. Therefore I set out to identify that specific range, as it is not fixed in either start or end position.

Using a simple loop over column A I'm able to match against the text that is always contained in the first row of the specific area I'm interested in.

Now the amount of rows that follows is variable. The upside is that its always followed by an empty row.

So I thought to make use of the vba equivalent of ctrl+shift+down `Cell(startrow,1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count`

This however doesn't return the correct result, 23 instead of 21.
When I do the ctrl+shift+down manual, it does select the right set of cells.

I decided to play around a little, and it looks like it takes two cells above the start cell to be included into the `CurrentRegion`, those cells are blank too.

Is there an alternative way to count the number of continous cells that contain data from a given start cell, without looping through all cells?

**Edit: Some sample data:**

```
row# - Cell content
71   - blank
72   - "xx" 'Match for startrow
73   - 1
74   - 2
.......
92   - 20
93   - blank
94   - blank
95   - "xx" 'next block of data.
```

I have a way to find the start row, so then `Range("A72").CurrentRange` should be 72 to 92, ie 21 rows.

Comment: You're not using the equivalent of ctrl+shift+down.  Try something like Cells(1,1).End(xldown).row so you're specifying a starting location and then going down to the last contiguous cell.  I may be wrong, but my understanding of CurrentRegion and UsedRange is they can account for previously used cells, so that can lead to issues.

Comment: What is the populated range on the sheet? It's address. And yes, as above from @Cyril

Comment: @QHarr My data I'm interested in starts in row 72 for example, and then is 21 rows, including 72. Its is both pre- and superceded by empty cells. The populated range is somewhere between 4 and XX columns, and from row 1 to in the 150's, containing a lot of blanks.

Comment: @Cyrill I started with a point, to indicate that this follows a reference. Included that more explicitly now.

Comment: @ScottCraner, my question is **not** about finding the last row in use in a worksheet, rather the last continuous row in a range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After re-reading the question I noticed you have blank cells above what you are trying to count, rendering my lastrow count useless.  You could always find the start position, end position, and calculate the number of rows between the two.

Just as an example:

```
startRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

rowCount = (lastRow - startRow) + 1
```

This goes from `A1` downward, until it finds the first nonblank cell and stores that row number in the variable `startRow`.  Then, it does what I originally stated, pulls the lastrow and stores that value in `lastRow`.  Lastly it will just calculate the difference between the lastrow and the startrow.  If the first value is a title of somesort, and you do not want it counted then remove the `() + 1`, but typically that'll be required in this situation to get a full count of the rows in that range.

---

Edit -

Per your comment, you have the startRow, and you are not interested in seeing the last row of the workbook - but instead are interested just in the range of cells after your startRow.  Another option you may have would be using `.Find` on a full range of cells (starting with your start row).  For example:

```
startRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lSheetRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = .Range("A" & startRow & ":A" & lSheetRow).Find(What:="", _
        Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlDown, _
        MatchCase:=False).Row
End With

RowCount = lastRow - startRow
```

Now, what this is doing is exactly what I said before.  Finding your start row (which you already have) and storing it as `startRow`; then finding the last row of the sheet (which you already have) and storing it as `lastRow`.  This is going to be the range that we look in.  Realistically you don't have to do it this way, I just wanted to incorporate the variables I already had.

Then with whichever sheet you are doing this with (change naming conventions based on your workbook) it is storing a new variable, `lastRow` equivalent to finding the first blank cell within the range we are choosing.  In this case it's searching inbetween the Start Row and the Last Row of the sheet.  Then, it's subtracting the Start Row from the newly determined Last Row (or first blank row after your start row) and is showing how many continuous cells of data there are.

I created a new workbook and enterted your data into it, the `RowCount` variable was stored as 21.

Comment: as indicated in my question, I already know the start row. Also I'm not interested in the final row of the sheet, just the last continuos row in the range.

Comment: @Luuklag, I added a new solution as an edit.  It's using `.Find` and it worked with a sample set of your exact data.  Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. The current region is limited by **completely** blank rows or columns. Whilst my cell `A71`is blank `B71`is not, nor is `A70`. So starting at `A72` by definition also includes `A71`and `A70`, hence the incorrect results. Now going to insert a blank row above the start row to make accurate calculations.