# How to properly count visible rows in VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Consider this list in excel:

[image]

That aims to count those visible rows. So I have this Module (Macro):

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rCount As Long, x As Long
Dim rng As Range
Sub printTest()
    Dim content As String
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    rCount = 0
    
    For x = 4 To ws.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        If ws.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            rCount = rCount + 1
            content = content & " " & ws.Cells(x, 1)
        End If
    Next x
    MsgBox "Visisble Row: " & rCount & " Content: " & content
End Sub
```

As you see in the `Message box` it does not include all my visible rows. What I am missing in my code? Hope someone can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CurrentRegion.Row.Count returns incorrect number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860772/currentregion-row-count-returns-incorrect-number)

Comment: `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` would be the right approach here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your CurrentRegion is `A3:B13`,  `ws.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count` will return 11 (as the range contains 11 rows). Now you loop from row 4 to row 11 of the *worksheet* and not the *range* and therefore you see only the data until row 11, not 13.

The following code uses the fact that every range has again a `Cells`-property and loops over the cells of the Range:

```
Dim r As Range, x As Long, rCount As Long, content As String
Set r = ws.Range("A4").CurrentRegion
For x = 2 To r.Rows.Count
    If Not r.Cells(x, 1).EntireRow.Hidden Then
        rCount = rCount + 1
        content = content & " " & r.Cells(x, 1)
    End If
Next
Debug.Print content
```

An alternative is to use the `SpecialCells`-method with the parameter `xlCellTypeVisible` - that will return only the visible cells of a Range. However, be aware that this will lead to a runtime error if no cells are visible:

```
content = ""
Dim cell As Range
Set r = ws.Range("A10").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
For x = 2 To r.Cells.Count
    content = content & " " & r.Cells(x)
Next
Debug.Print content
```